# LINQ Aggregate function is not working properly after 13 factorial?

Tags: c#, linq, factorial

For my curiosity I am writing a code to find the factorial of large number eg:25. For that I wrote the below code. I use BigInteger as it can store value of any length as define per memory.

```cs
int a = 13;
BigInteger factorial1 = a == 0 ? 1 : Enumerable.Range(1, a).Aggregate((i, j) => i * j); // Aggregate function not working properly after 12 factorial

Console.WriteLine(factorial1);
```

But surprisingly, I don't get the correct answer. I tried for smaller number upto 12 factorial and it gives correct answer but for 13 and beyond, the answer is wrong.

I have tried this very simple code which gives the correct answer.

```cs
BigInteger factorial3 = 1;
while (n > 0)
{
    factorial3 = factorial3 * n;
    --n;
}
Console.WriteLine(factorial3);
```

But the problem here is that BigInteger is immutable. So the above code will have a large memory foot print which is not desirable.

Comment: What do you believe the value of 13 factorial to be? And what is the range of valid `int` values? (Note how you're using `int` in the first example, *not* `BigInteger`.) Hint: this has nothing to do with LINQ really, and it's definitely not a problem with `Aggregate`.

Comment: You're using `int`, not `BigInteger`

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> Enumerable.Range(int start, int count)`, not a single mention of `BigInteger `

Comment: when you really need that huge numbers, you need that much memory. It's as easy as this. You can chose `long`, but even than you'll end up anyway.

Comment: BigIntegers are immutable structs.  So are ints.  BigIntegers can consume memory (because, well, they are big), but the nature of structs is that assignment is a value copy, so you shouldn't be seeing an overly large memory footprint.

Comment: @Flydog57: That depends on the values... because the size has to be variable, `BigInteger` (outside the range of `int`) allocates an array, which is obviously on the heap, and needs to be garbage collected. So there's a significant difference there in terms of heap allocation. (But of course creating just a few BigIntegers will not have a "large" memory footprint...)

Answer (score 3):

You should specify starting aggregation value, it should be `BigInteger.One`:

```
BigInteger factorial1 = a == 0 ? 1 : Enumerable
  .Range(1, a)
  .Aggregate(BigInteger.One, (i, j) => i * j);
```

otherwise for `.Aggregate((i, j) => i * j)` the result will be of type `int` (since both `i` and `j` are `int`) and only then (after *integer overflow*, `13! = 6227020800 > int.MaxValue = 2147483647`) it will be cast to `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-7.0) produces `int`s, not `BigInteger`s. `Enumerable.Range(1, a).Aggregate((i, j) => i * j);` uses `Int32` throughout and ends up overflowing after 13.

To avoid overflow you need to convert those integers to BigInteger before processing them:

```
var n=Enumerable.Range(1, 13).Select(i=>(BigInteger)i)
                             .Aggregate((i, j) => i * j);
```

This produces `6227020800`

Another option is to create your own `Range` method that creates `BigInteger` values :

```
public static IEnumerable<BigInteger> BigRange(BigInteger start,int count)
{
    for(var i=start;i<start+count;i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}

...

var n=BigRange(1, 13).Aggregate((i, j) => i * j);
```

Comment: Thank You Every One for your help